# Microwave oven with no heat, Bad design or wrong component choice?

Tags: switches, circuit-design, circuit-protection, microwave

Few days ago, my Magic Chef MCD990B microwave oven magically passed away randomly and so suddenly that I didn't even have time to say goodbye, not that I have used it heavily or considered it as my friend, but still, it was a sad day for me.

Today, I finally got off my ass (It's just an expression, stop being so sensitive), and took it apart, not trying to kill myself because I am sad or anything, although it could be deadly if done incorrectly, but trying to save the environment, and it's not like I can afford to buy another one of those thing anyway.

Since I am not an expert in microwave oven and I hardly even know how to boil a pot of water, I asked my old girl, ms.google. According to her, 3 main reasons that a microwave oven appears to work, but produces no heat are: 1, bad high voltage diode; 2, bad door switch, and 3, bad magnetron.

While I know what a diode is and how it works, the high voltage part of the description scared the hell out of me, so I decided to follow the instructions given by a random gentleman from Youtube to test that diode, and it turned out fine.

My oven comes with 3 door switches, and I tested all of them using my old meter, and they turned out fine too, so as the magnetron. I also took apart the main board and checked the 12v relay and every things looked good to me.

Finally, after 2 hours of messing with this dead microwave oven, I though I had figured out what the real problem is, and I was right. The problem for this over-priced oven is not from a 10 cents badly made capacitor, but from over-used of bad connectors. **Oxidation** have formed on all of those 3 latch-door switches due to the high current passing them.

[image]

[image]

Surprisingly, the microwave oven is a very simple device. While I don't have a circuit diagram for this, I can tell that the main power for the transformer go through all 3 of these switches and a relay in the main logic board, so there are actually 4x2+2(for transformer)+2 (for the power input)= 12 of those kind of haphazardly connected connectors to deliver the high current to run a high power microwave oven. To be fair, the connector for the relay is pretty tight.

[image]

**Question 1**, My oven is less than 1 year old. Are those switches bad design or planned obsolescence or something else?

**Question 2**, I know safety is very important for these kinda of oven, so they use 3 door switches, but would it make more sense to use low current switches and use the main logic board to control the power? They are using a relay to control the power anyway.

**Question 3**, I have used sand paper to scratch off the oxidation, but I can tell oxidation will form soon, since those connectors are very loose, and I think I can actually hear sparks coming from the oven once microwaving. Is there a way to avoid oxidation? Soldering is not an option, since the space is so tight.

Comment: Why you are so sure that the magnetron is OK? Does the oven work after you cleaned up the contacts, or else?

Comment: @Ali Chen it works after cleaning up the taps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Maybe the connectors were assembled badly or the metallurgy is a bit off. Hard to tell. It's almost surely the female portion which is causing the trouble. Hard to make a tab wrong, but the other bit has the springiness which is essential. It's also possible there is something in your environment (sulfur?) which is corrosive, which could be contributing but there should be enough pressure that is not a problem, especially at mains voltage.
2. Nothing beats directly interrupting the power in a permissive chain. Certainly nothing with firmware. Imagine if that relay stuck and all you did was the next best thing and interrupted the coil power- fried corneas or hands - maybe permanent damage. And in any case, your intuition is wrong in this case, lower voltage low current connections are more prone to failing open than those at mains voltage.
3. **The problem is that the female connectors are loose**, nothing to do with the tabs. You can replace the female [Faston (quick disconnect)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FASTON_terminal) connectors with fresh ones of the correct size and with appropriate approvals and rating- you just lose a bit of wire length.

The spring action is just the bending of the metal as shown below:

[image]

Cheaper ones will use thin brass, which doesn't make a very good spring, better ones phosphor bronze, and there are also construction differences as you can see in [this](http://www.te.com/commerce/DocumentDelivery/DDEController?Action=srchrtrv&DocNm=82004_FASTON_TERMINALS_-_FULL_CATALOG&DocType=CS&DocLang=EN) catalog (which might be a bit overwhelming).

Be careful and/or get help on this, there are lots of things there that can hurt you, and microwave ovens are stupidly cheap (unless you need one to fit a specific hole, then not so much).

Comment: 1, All 6 of those female connectors are very loose. and if you look at reviews across the internet about this model of microwave oven, then you can tell that it's not a rare a anomaly. Those connectors do have a spring, but it's for locking the cable to the tab, not for tightness. 2, Can you use simple hardware, ie a simple transistor powering a relay circuit to power it? and there are empty slots for the extra relays in the PCB. 3, yes, you are right. I may able to replace them.

Comment: You will need the terminals and a decent crimp tool (neither is very expensive). Or return the oven under warranty.

Comment: For precision fix , find some scrap hard sheet plastic to cut with scissors that fits inside   Faston plug thickness as a shim and then crimp gently with pliers ,but not excessive so it can be withdrawn. The interference fit should be tight to connect then it will have the low contact resistance to be reliable.

Comment: @TonyStewartolderthandirt  You have more faith in the crappy OEM terminals than I do. They will likely just loosen up again from self-heating and cooling. < 100% power (eg. defrost) is probably particularly bad. I bet they were tight when they went on in the first place.

Comment: I don't know what size it's. Guess I will buy all 3 standards: 6.3/4.8/2.8MM. One should fit?

Comment: Good quality Japan Steel terminals will have high strength steel yet springy over range of interference, cheaper steel alloys may have lower strength but still give adequate tension from interference fit,  if re-crimped as I suggested to give a snug fit.  Quality aspects can certainly vary, but microwave oven temperature rise is not as significant as the annealing process.

Comment: I looked up similar specs from OMRON and they are 6.3mm. Got a ruler?  Don't guess.  Next question. Do you know how to test a proper wire crimp to a good Faston plug? 2 kg yank on wire to crimp.  ( or 5 lb pull test)

Comment: Microwave oven door switches are actually a very carefully designed fail safe mechanism, there are two sets of contacts, a normally open one that is in series with the supply, and a normally closed one that is wired to short circuit the supply is it is energised with the door open, the door cam is designed to open the normally closed contact just before it closes the normally open power contact, so that in the event of the power contact welding, opening the door will blow the fuse.  Do not mess with this, it is THE safety critical component.